# Confusing behavior when using TypeVar with dataclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, python-dataclasses

If I define a type like the following:

```py
StringType = TypeVar('StringType', str, None)
```

Then I can use it in my class or function definitions:

```py
class StringClass:
    def __init__(self, s: StringType = None):
        self.s = s

def func(s: StringType = None):
    return s
```

My type checker, `Pylance`, works great!

But if I define my class using dataclass:

```py
@dataclass
class StringClass:
    s: StringType = None
```

Then Pylance complains: `Type variable "StringType" has no meaning in this context`

I do not understand why the second definition using `dataclass` does not work.

Can someone explain this to me, and hopefully explain how to get dataclass to work with the new type?

Comment: This does not seem to be a usage scenario for `TypeVar`, just simply use `typing.Optional[str]` or `str | None`.

Comment: Keep in mind that the type here is just an example. The actual real-word types I use are more complicated than this (e.g. `str | None | QuerySet | ModelBase`)

Comment: I can't see whether the type is complex has any effect, because in my opinion, this is not a scenario where `TypeVar` should be used. Refer to [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar), "*They serve as the parameters for generic types as well as for generic function definitions.*"

Comment: Going over the definition, it seems you are correct. But this then changes my question to how I can use generic types to accomplish the type checking listed in my post. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's look at what you've got right now.

```
StringType = TypeVar('StringType', str, None)
```

This is a type variable, i.e. a generic. It is *not* saying that `StringType` is an alias to `str | None`. It is saying that `StringType` is a variable that *may* be introduced into a scope later, and if it is then its possible values are `str` or `None`.

Now Python is unfortunately weird about when it introduces type variables into scope. In a language like Java, it's always explicit (i.e. anytime you want to introduce a type variable, you explicitly write it in brackets as `<T>`). But Python's rules are different.

- If a type variable (which is not already in scope) is used in a function, including a member function, then the function itself becomes generic.
- If a type variable is used in the parent class declaration of a class, then the whole class becomes generic.

Your dataclass doesn't fit into either of these situations. The dataclass variable isn't a function argument, nor is it a parent class designator, so your type checker gets confused.

So your current constructor code

```
class StringClass:
    def __init__(self, s: StringType = None):
        self.s = s
```

is similar to this Java code (pseudocode, since we can't represent the constraint `str | None` exactly in Java)

```
public class StringClass {
    public Object s;
    public<T> StringClass(T s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

That is, the class itself is *not* generic. It's the constructor that is, and the instance variable `s` on the class is inferred to be the *least-upper bound* of the valid types for the type variable. In Java, that's `Object`, and in Python (which has union types), that's `str | None`.

As pointed out in the comments, what you probably want is a union type.

```
class StringClass:
    def __init__(self, s: str | None = None):
        self.s = s
```

And you can alias these just like anything else.

```
StringType = str | None
```

(Note: If you're using a Python version older than 3.10, you'll need to use [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) instead, since the [`|` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) is not permitted at runtime until Python 3.10. the type checker will have no issue with it either way)

However, if you want your class to be generic, then you want the *whole* class to be generic, not just the constructor.

```
class StringClass(Generic[StringType]):
    def __init__(self, s: StringType = None):
        self.s = s
```

[`typing.Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) is a superclass designed specifically to introduce type variables. It does nothing else and does not add any methods to the class (except some reflection stuff to allow the `[]` syntax to work). Now your constructor isn't generic but your whole class is. You refer, in types, to `StringClass` with a type argument as `StringClass[str]` or `StringClass[None]`.

This approach extends to your dataclass just fine. Dataclasses can have arbitrary superclasses, including `Generic`.

```
@dataclass
class StringClass(Generic[StringType]):
    s: StringType = None
```

Now the type variable is in scope, as it was introduced by the class itself, so it can be used in the instance fields just fine.

So, depending on your use case, I recommend either (1) introducing the type variable at class scope rather than constructor scope, or (2) declaring a type *alias* rather than a type variable, and using that. The question of which one to use comes down to whether or not, in your situation, it makes sense to keep track of the *actual* type of the argument at compile-time. With the first approach, you'll be able to write `StringClass[None]` or `StringClass[str]` or similar in order to further restrict the type of `StringClass` that you expect in a particular situation. This can be useful but can also get tedious if you don't often need to know that information.

---

**EDIT:** I see the comments on the question now. Based on what you're describing, I think the type alias fits your use case better. So write

```
StringType = str | None | QuerySet | ModelBase
```

or, for Python 3.9 and older,

```
StringType = Union[str, None, QuerySet, ModelBase]
```

Comment: Thank you @Silvio! This is exactly the answer I was looking for. 
Much appreciated!

Comment: note that even for Python 3.9 and older, you can still use the `|` syntax. the annotation simply needs to be wrapped in quotes, like `'..'`

Comment: @rv.kvetch I suggested that in my original version of this post. But unfortunately, type aliases don't seem to get recognized if they're quoted strings, at least in mypy (maybe other type checkers do better). mypy, at least, treats `StringType = 'str | None'` as an ordinary variable declaration and not the name of a type alias. And the [annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeAlias) that would fix the problem was also introduced in Python 3.10.